# hello guys, i get error to display youtube video when i hosting my webiste in cpanel, but in localhost it runs well

Tags: php, laravel

i get error in blade like this *Call to a member function getIframe() on boolean*
Here my code in blade

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
    {!! Embed::make($video->video)->parseUrl()->getIframe() !!}
@endforeach
```

i hope someone help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any external library? If so, check the versions, maybe the package was updated and `parseUrl` method would return `bool` instead of `object` on the new one

Comment: no, i install library via composer.

Comment: That's what I meant.. on your local env you might have a different version than on your server

Comment: so, can you give solution to solve it..thanks

Comment: The solution is to check if that's the reason of your error. Check the package version on your local env and the package version on your server. If they are different then set the local version to composer to get the same version to your server too

Comment: ok,i'm going to try it. thanks

Comment: still no solved, i have checked the package version and same.